# How to set state in kendo-ui dropdown

Tags: reactjs, kendo-ui

How do I use the state value using kendo-ui dropdown as functional component? Trying to print the 
  selected item in meny but getting error as
  Uncaught Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React 
  child (found: object with keys {CategoryName}). If you meant to render a collection of children, 
  use an array instead. How do I use the state value? I do not want to use class components. Here is 
   my code :

`````
    import React,{Component,useState } from 'react';
    import './App.css';
    import { DropDownList } from '@progress/kendo-react-dropdowns';
    import '@progress/kendo-theme-material/dist/all.css'; 
    import categories from './categories.json';

   function App() {
   const [dropdownlistCategory,setValues] = useState(null);
    function handleDropDownChange(event){
     setValues(() => ({
       [event.target.name]: event.target.value,
     }));
   }

  return (
   <div className="App">
     <h1>Hello KendoReact!</h1>
     <p>
      <DropDownList
       name = "CategoryName"
       data={categories}
       dataItemKey="CategoryID"
       textField="CategoryName"
       defaultItem={{CategoryID: null, CategoryName: "Product categories"}}
       onChange = {handleDropDownChange}
       />
     </p>
    <p>
      Selected item is {dropdownlistCategory}
    </p>
    </div>
   );
  }

   export default App;
 ````

  Trying to print the selected item in meny but getting error as '
   react-dom.development.js:14850 Uncaught Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React 
  child (found: object with keys {CategoryName}). If you meant to render a collection of children, 
use an array instead. 
 How do I use the state value?'
`````

Answer (score 0):

This kind of error occurs when you try to display contents of object directly inside a component without looping over it.
So whenever you have an object and you want its data to be displayed try to map over it.